# Perl comprehensive phone number regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that contains phone numbers of the following formats:

```
(xxx) xxx.xxxx
(xxx).xxx.xxxx
(xxx) xxx-xxxx
(xxx)-xxx-xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxxx
xxx-xxx-xxxx
xxx xxx-xxxx
xxx xxx.xxxx
```

I must parse the file for phone numbers of those and ONLY those formats, and output them to a separate file. I'm using perl, and so far I have what I think is a valid regex for two of these numbers

```
my $phone_regex = qr/^(\d{3}\-)?(\(\d{3}\))?\d{3}\-\d{4}$/;
```

But I'm not sure if this is correct, or how to do the rest all in one regex. Thank you!

Comment: For difficult regexes it might be helpful to define sub-regexes, e.g. `$three_digits = qr/\d{3}/;` and then combine them to each case you list as another sub-regex and then combine those 8 regexes to the final regex.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't escaped parenthesis properly and have uselessly escaped hyphen which isn't needed. The regex you are trying to create is this,

```
^\(?\d{3}\)?[ .-]\d{3}[ .-]\d{4}$
```

Explanation:

- `^` -
- `\(?` - Optional starting parenthesis `(`
- `\d{3}` - Followed by three digits
- `\)?` - Optional closing parenthesis `)`
- `[ .-]` - A single character either a space or `.` or `-`
- `\d{3}` - Followed by three digits
- `[ .-]` - Again a single character either a space or `.` or `-`
- `\d{4}` - Followed by four digits
- `$` - End of string

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BPFJT4/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
\(?\d{3}\)?[-. ]\d{3}[-. ]\d{4}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vQCGyf/1/).

---

Broken down this is

```
\(?   # "(", optional
\d{3} # three digits
\)?   # ")", optional
[-. ] # one of "-", "." or " "
\d{3} # three digits
[-. ] # same as above
\d{4} # four digits
```

If you want, you can add word boundaries on the right site (`\b`), some potential matches may be filtered out then.

Comment: this worked except it matched a phone number with a closing parens but without an opening parens . ex `323) 729-9329`

Answer (score 1):

Your current regex allows too much, as it will allow `xxx-(xxx)` at the beginning. It also doesn't handle any of the `.` or space separated cases. You want to have only three sets of digits, and then allow optional parentheses around the first set which you can use an [alternation](https://perldoc.pl/perlretut#Matching-this-or-that) for, and then you can make use of [character classes](https://perldoc.pl/perlretut#Using-character-classes) to indicate the set of separators you want to allow.

Additionally, don't use `\d` as it will match any unicode digit. Since you likely only want to allow ASCII digits, use the character class `[0-9]` (there are other options, but this is the simplest).

Finally, `$` allows a newline at the end of the string, so use `\z` instead which does not. Make sure if you are reading these from a file that you [chomp](https://perldoc.pl/functions/chomp) them so they do not contain trailing newlines.

This leaves us with:

```
qr/^(?:[0-9]{3}|\([0-9]{3}\))[-. ][0-9]{3}[-.][0-9]{4}\z/
```

If you want to ensure that the two separators are the same if the first is a `.` or `-`, it is easiest to do this in multiple regex checks (these can be more lenient since we already validated the general format):

```
if ($str =~ m/^[0-9()]+ /
    or $str =~ m/^[0-9()]+\.[0-9]{3}\./
    or $str =~ m/^[0-9()]+-[0-9]{3}-/) {
    # allowed
}
```

Comment: Also, when the first delimiter is . or -, needs to restrict the second delimiter to that

Comment: @ysth I fixed the first by using an alternation instead, and added an option for checking the second (while it's possible to do in one regex, it would be unnecessarily complex)